# My spoiler tags are occasionally not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bug, spoilers

In [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42695/29343) my spoiler tags were not working, as the ! character is ignored and displayed, as if it was quoted text. How do I get a workaround of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed it for you.

## This is HTML, and you can learn it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Spoiler tags don't work when you try and have paragraphs

For instance:

> !This spoiler tag
>   doesn't work

Because I have written:

```
>!This spoiler tag
doesn't work
```

And the new line causes an error

## If you want to add a new line then add

`<br>`

which means line break.

So now

> This spoiler tag
> works :P

Because I wrote

```
>!This spoiler tag<br>works :P
```

Alternatively you can write

```
>!This spoiler tag<br>
>!works :P
```

and you still get

> A spoiler tag
> that works :P

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I was struggling with this in more than one of my posts.

Comment: @Matsmath, added a place where you can learn about it

Comment: (+1) for `:P` :P

Answer (score 5):

You has a paragraph break in the middle of your spoilertag, which caused it not to work properly. @BeastlyGerbil has now fixed this.

---

For future reference, paragraph breaks don't work very well with spoilertags. You need to include a double space at the end of every line, including the black line between paragraphs. Doing this:

```
>! stuff

>! more stuff
```

gives this output:

> ! stuff
>
> ! more stuff

So you have to do this:

```
>! stuff  
>!  
>! more stuff
```

to get the desired output:

> stuff
>
>  more stuff

Comment: Thanks! I am going to accept the other answer because @Beasty Gerbil actually fixed the issue.

Comment: Well, at least you don't get rep for an accept :P